# Unable to get provider DummyContentProvider after upgrading gradle dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am updating `com.google.android.gms` and firebase gradle dependencies to fix the error described here: [Unable to start receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340333/unable-to-start-receiver-com-google-firebase-iid-firebaseinstanceidinternalrecei). I was using
 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`. Using versions above that seems to cause the following stack trace during `adb logcat`.

Why is this error caused?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 12:21:11.721 11491 11491 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.netbeast.yeti.debug,
  PID: 11491 05-15 12:21:11.721 11491 11491 E AndroidRuntime: 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider 
  com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.DummyContentProvider:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
  "com.marianhello.bgloc.sync.DummyContentProvider"
  on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.netbeast.yeti.debug-2/base.apk"],
  nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.startup.app.debug-2/lib/arm, 
  /data/app/com.startup.app.debug-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, 
  /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

For more info: the error comes from a library used in the native side. This is a project with react native that has a package called `react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation`